# Unable to disable paper-item in Polymer 0.5

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am a novice with js, polymer and basically web programming. Kindly excuse my limited knowledge.

I have a situation where I need to disable a `<paper-item>` element inside a `<paper-dropdown>` based on some conditions. I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
<paper-item id = "startButton" class="menu_item" disabled?="{{!ready}}" >Start</paper-item>.
```

The ready flag is being extended from another page via the `extends in polymer-element`.  I even passed a direct boolean value like `disabled?="{{true}}"` but there is no change in the way the paper-item looks. It is still selectable.

Even this

```
<paper-item id = "startButton" class="menu_item" disabled>Start</paper-item>
```

doesn't work.

I am using Polymer 0.5, not sure if this issue is fixed in 1.0. However, I cant switch to 1.0 at this stage.

Is there a way to solve this issue without switching to 1.0

Answer (score 1):

You can override this by adding a "disabled" attribute to the polymer element. At least this works in polymer 1.0 not sure of 0.5.

You might want to have a look @ https://github.com/Polymer/core-menu/issues/8

Comment: You mean <paper-item id = "startButton" class="menu_item" disabled>Start</paper-item> ? Doesn't work in 0.5, at this stage I can't switch to 1.0, I need to use 0.5 only.

Comment: Yes... now that u have added an attribute. Add a css selector something like the following to the style attribute of this element      *[disabled] {
      color: #D3D3D3;
      pointer-events: none;
    }